# webrtc peer connection does not provide remote video track

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, webrtc

## Background

I'm creating an iOS app that enables video chat between an iOS client and a web browser using [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/) (I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC-iOS) for iOS)

## Problem

`Given` I'm testing connection in local home network
`When` rtc connection established
`Then` I could not render remote video

## Analysis

For `RTCPeerConnection` there is following `constraints`:

```
[[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
            initWithMandatoryConstraints:nil
            optionalConstraints:@{@"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": @"true"}];
```

and following configuration:

```
RTCConfiguration *config = [[RTCConfiguration alloc] init];
    config.iceServers = @[[self STUNServer]];
```

then I'm adding local stream:

```
- (RTCMediaStream *)createLocalMediaStreamWithVideoTrack:(RTCVideoTrack *__autoreleasing *)videoTrack {
    RTCMediaStream* localStream = [self.factory mediaStreamWithStreamId:@"ARDAMS"];

    RTCVideoTrack *localVideoTrack = [self createLocalVideoTrack];
    if (localVideoTrack) {
        [localStream addVideoTrack:localVideoTrack];
    }
    if (videoTrack) {
        (*videoTrack) = localVideoTrack;
    }

    [localStream addAudioTrack:[self.factory audioTrackWithTrackId:@"ARDAMSa0"]];
    return localStream;
}
- (RTCVideoTrack *)createLocalVideoTrack {
    RTCVideoTrack *localVideoTrack = nil;
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [HAHRTCDefaults mediaStreamConstraints];
    RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [self.factory avFoundationVideoSourceWithConstraints:mediaConstraints];
    localVideoTrack = [self.factory videoTrackWithSource:videoSource trackId:@"ARDAMSv0"];
#endif
    return localVideoTrack;
}
```

Once negotiation needed I'm creating an offer with following constraints:

```
NSDictionary *mandatoryConstraints = @{@"OfferToReceiveAudio": @"true",
                                       @"OfferToReceiveVideo": @"true"};
RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =
    [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
        initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
        optionalConstraints:nil];
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/abbood/1233247005d7f88c10b6ecc71ca21ac9) is Local Session Description:

[Here](https://gist.github.com/abbood/fe868ed113079ac1ca03ea20af31d6d8) are Local Ice Candidates:

[Here](https://gist.github.com/abbood/5dd5737289529e9e4c94a7c9bb34cf98) is Remote Session Description

Here are Remote's Ice Candidates:

```
audio
0
candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.0.100 57752 typ host

audio
0
candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 212.90.61.183 57752 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 57752
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me know where to get the latest code to work with https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC-iOS?

Comment: Did you found any way for this, even I am facing similar issue

Comment: hi, did you found the solution to your problem?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Did you find a solution?